# Joystick App for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, android, joystick

I am trying to use my Android Phone as Joystick for Ubuntu 18.04. I do not want to develop the app from scratch and wanted to know if there is an app on Google Play store which can be used towards this? My main purpose is to increase the range of my joystick using WiFi

Comment: Does that mean you get to use Android phone as Joystick with limited range ?

Comment: It means that I want to use my phone as joystick so that I can use WiFi rather than Bluetooth which is conventionally used in joystick

Comment: I mean, are you able to use it right now ? Either through Bluetooth or WiFi ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best options that you can try is `Ultimate Gamepad`. It turns your phone into a multitouch joystick and supports Wifi / Bluetooth. You can download the app from Google PlayStore [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.negusoft.ugamepad&hl=en).

For this app to work, you have to install the `Ultimate Control Receiver` program on your computer, this software is multiplatform so it's available for PC, Mac and GNU Linux (Ubuntu), and can be downloaded from [here](http://www.negusoft.com/index.php/ultimate-control/downloads). After that, you have to select it from the list displayed on your phone.

`Ultimate Gamepad` provides a real button emulation, press several buttons with your thumb as you would on a regular controller.

A second option that you could try is `DroidPad`, it lets you use an Android powered phone as a Joystick on a computer (Windows or GNU Linux). You can connect via USB or WiFi.

You can get more details about this app in its official website [here](https://www.digitalsquid.co.uk/droidpad/).

Hope it helps.